# OS X: how to execute java run command in OSX

Tags: java, terminal, classpath

Perviously I used Windows 7 and to execute Java app I used:

```
\bin>java -classpath .;lib\* com.runtime.Main --nocache tv.net.Experiment
```

How I can do It in OS X 10.9?

I used:

```
:bin$ java -classpath ../lib com.runtime.Main --nocache tv.net.Experiment
Error: Could not find or load main class com.runtime.Main
```

Comment: That's simply telling you that `com.runtime.Main` is not on your classpath.  Please double-check your assumptions about the contents of `../lib` ;)

Comment: In "bin" folder I have folders "lib" - where my jar libs placed; "tv" - folder with my classes; "com" - folder with also my classes

Answer (score 0):

After some research found what I need.
OS X version of the command look look this:

```
:bin$ java -classpath .:lib/* com.runtime.Main --nocache tv.net.Experiment
```